# Reading Java Stream Objects from input stream

Tags: java, objectinputstream

I have a problem with `java.lang.Object` stream. InputStream actually is a real Object[]. readObject method reads only one object. How can I read stream objects correctly? Sample code is below.

```java
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    InputStream stream = request.getInputStream();
    byte[] streamBytes = stream.readAllBytes();
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(streamBytes);
    ObjectInput in = null;
    try {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        Object o = in.readObject();

        System.out.println(o.getClass()); // Prints: class [Ljava.lang.Object;
        System.out.println(o.getClass().getSimpleName()); // Prints: Object[]

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: An array is also a type of object. So your code read an object, and that object is an array, containing other objects. Cast it to `Object[]` and you're good to go. That said, in general I would recommend you avoid using Java serialization, and instead use XML or JSON style serialization, as that is more portable.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You are saying as ```Object[] objects = (Object[]) o``` I am new to Java. Can you help me about syntax?

Comment: You are right. XML or JSON would be a good choice. this object contains binary data. I didn't develop this API. I am sending http request to external API endpoint.

Comment: `ObjectInputStream` is outdated and can be insecure (code injection into Java app9 if you don't use `setObjectInputFilter` (requires Java 9) on it and configure the stream correctly.

Comment: You don't need half of this code. `ois - new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream())` and a loop calling `ois.readObject()` will do, terminating when `EOFException` is caught. You don't need `readAllBytes()` or the `ByteArrayInputStream()`: both are just a waste of time and space.